# Interrupt choice command in batch files

Tags: batch-file

In a batch file I'm currently writing, I'm making use of the choice commmand to ask the user what the program should do:

```
choice /n /c:sen /d n /t %duration%
```

%duration% is a variable that has already been acquired, so there's no need to worry about it. Let's just say it's 100 for now, and my script looks like this:

```
@echo off
set duration=100
choice /n /c:sen /d n /t %duration%
```

Now, what I want to be able to do, is somehow interrupt this command using a different (batch) file. So, what should technically happen, is that the choice command waits for input for 100 seconds unless the second script is run, after wich the choice command should be interrupted and the script should move on to the next command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"taskkill /im choice.exe /f" -- will kill all choice.exe processes running at that moment.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot that choice.exe was a separate process.